# Canon SDK API reference doesn't contain all the property value codes needed

Tags: c#, sdk, edsdk, canon-sdk

I'm trying to work with Canon Mark III camera having EDSDK 2.14.
I can't parse all the hex codes for aperture, exposure, ISO and white balance values available.
There're some codes in the SDK API Reference, but the camera returns about twice more different values. So, I can't convert to human-readable values about a half of all the ISO values available.
Is the version 2.14 obsolete for Mark III? How can I find the complete conversion table?

Comment: I assume you mean the EOS 5D MkIII. Support for this camera was added with SDK version 2.11. Comparing the specs of the camera and all defined values of the SDK, I can't find any missing definitions. Can you add more specific details?

Comment: As to camera specs, all of them are covered by the SDK. However, when I try to request values available, using EdsGetPropertyDesc method and then getting PropDesc property value of the EdsPropertyDesc (as far as I've understood, it's recommended way to get all the values available), it returns a lot of additional values, that aren't covered by the SDK.
Maybe, I'm wrong, and EdsGetPropertyDesc / .PropDesc can't be used to get all the values available? In case that's the point, how can I do that instead?

Comment: using EdsGetPropertyDesc is correct yes. Here would be a working C# example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp#AvailableSettings Hope this clears any confusion